# How to pass argument from parsed json value to onclick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We have a table with data. My goal is to pass an argument from parsed JSON value to another javascript function - named `newStory(value['stories'])` from onclick method.

Tried a lot of different methods with no success..

```
json[key]['date'] = '<span class="' + styleBlock + '">' + value['date'] + '</span>'; 
json[key]['category'] = '<span class="' + styleCatDefault + '">' + value['category'] + '</span>';
json[key]['subcategory'] = '<span class="' + styleSubcatDefault + '">' + value['subcategory'] + '</span>';       
json[key]['stories'] = '<span><a href="#" onclick="newStory(value['stories'])">' + value['stories'] + '</a></span>';
```

Any help appreciated!

Edit:

Line with many quotes finally worked:

```
json[key]['stories'] = '<span><a href="#" onclick="newStory(' + "'" +value['stories'] + "'" + ')">' + value['stories'] + '</a></span>';
```

Comment: You just need to concatenate it's value in to the string properly, as you are in other places in the code sample. Better still, forget the inline click handler and use an unobtrusive, delegated one instead.

Comment: You could also escape the single quotes.

Comment: No, I can't. Undefined otherwise

Comment: I would suggest storing that value (or a reference to it) within the element.
As the click event gets first at a later time and most likely `value` is no longer set, you get the undefined error.

Comment: To do this, I would try something like `<a href="#" data-value="' + value['stories'] + '" onclick="newStory(this.attributes[\'data-value\'].value)" >' + value['stories'] + '</a>'`

Comment: Although I would rethink how you're coding this as I'm sure you could use a reference instead - possibly storing the JSON key in an attribute, then with you function `newStory` lookup the actual value using the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add value in string like this:

```
var str = `${jsvar}`
```

```js
json[key]['stories'] = `<span><a href="#" onclick="newStory(${value['stories']})">` + value['stories'] + '</a></span>';
```

Or

```
json[key]['stories'] = `<span><a href="#" onclick="newStory(${value['stories']})">${value['stories']}</a></span>`;
```